# Counterexample to Maschke's Theorem for $\text{char} K \mid |G|$

Tags: representation-theory, characters

Maschke's theorem states that for a finite group $G$ and a $K$-vector  space $V$ under the assumption of $\text{char} K \nmid |G|$, given a representation $\rho: G\to \text{GL}(V)$, every $G$-invariant $W\subset V$ admits a $G$-invariant complement $U$, i.e. $V=U\oplus W$.

I am given the following counterexample for $\text{char} K \mid |G|$: For $G=C_p = \{g^0,g^1,\ldots,g^{p-1}\}$, $K=\mathbb{F}_p$ and $V=K^2$, consider
$$\begin{align}
\rho: G &\to \text{GL}_2(K)\\\\
g^b &\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
1 & b\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}$$
I want to show that no such decomposition is possible in that case. My idea goes as follows:

Assume $V = U\oplus W = \langle (x_1,x_2)^t\rangle \oplus \langle (y_1,y_2)^t\rangle$ and WLOG $x_2\neq 0$. We have for all $g^b\in C_p$ that
$$
\rho(g^b)(x_1,x_2)^t = (x_1 + bx_2, x_2).$$
Since $U$ is $G$-invariant, $(x_1 + bx_2, x_2)\in U$, i.e. there is some $\lambda\in \mathbb{F}_p$ such that
$$
(x_1 + bx_2, x_2) = (\lambda x_1, \lambda x_2).
$$
Since $x_2=0$, the equality in the second component yields $\lambda=1$ and hence
$$
x_1 + bx_2 = \lambda x_1 \implies bx_2 = 0.
$$
Since this holds for all $b$, we have $x_2=0$, a contradiction.

Now, I do not see where I used the special property of the characteristic $p$ of $\mathbb{F}_p$ in my proof. Any details that I overlooked?

Comment: And you used the fact that the field has characteristic p in order to show that the matrix through which the element g acts has order p. Or at least, you should have ;-)

Comment: Oh, I see! So without that assumption $\rho$ just would not even necessarily be a homomorphism, right?

Comment: As an extra note: the same argument applied to the 'characteristic $0$ version' of this homomorphism can be used to show that Maschke's theorem fails for $G = \mathbb{Z}$, so the finite group condition is needed.